# Objective-C syntax error "Expected ']'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am attempting to configure cells in a `TableView`. One of the things I am trying to do is change the font and color of the text in the cells. Here is the code:

```
- (void)configureView {
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Thin" size:14];
    NSDictionary *cellAttributesDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName: cellFont];
}
```

At the colon after `NSFontAttributeName` I am getting the error `Expected ']'`. What is causing this error?

Comment: Formatting error. Your dictionary is not designated as a dictionary object. Change to this: `@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName: cellFont}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper syntax for a dictionary literal in Objective-C is `@{...};`

```
NSDictionary *cellAttributesDictionary = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName: cellFont};
```